# How to defer index of for loop till all promises are reslved

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a for loop inside which I have $q.all which makes calls to services. The calls are pushed to array as follow. The output that I am getting is values being assigned only to the last device.

[image: Output]

```
 for(device in self.listOfDevices){
                    var count =0;
                    var individualFixletCountPromise = [];
                    self.listOfDevices[device].count=0;
                    console.log("device level one"+device);
                    for(site in self.listOfDevices[device].sites){
                        individualFixletCountPromise.push(Bigfix.getPerSiteFixletCount(self.listOfDevices[device].sites[site].answer[0]));
                    }
                    $q.all(individualFixletCountPromise).then(function(response){
                        for(res in response){
                            var temp = response[res].data.data.replace(/type="integer"/g, '');
                            temp = temp.replace(/ >/g, '>');
                            var jsonObject = ngXml2json.parser(temp);
                            console.log(jsonObject.besapi.query.result.answer); 
                            count=count+jsonObject.besapi.query.result.answer;
                        }
                        console.log("device level two"+device);
                        self.listOfDevices[device].count=count;
                        console.log("assigned to self.ListOf devices:"+self.listOfDevices[device].count);
                    })

                }
```

Comment: try `for (let device in self.listOfDevices){` ...

Comment: That was so easy :) .. Can you explain why the behaviour is so? @JaromandaX

Comment: It's all about Closure

Comment: How can I make the outer loop also aynchronous so that all the data is displayed at once.